# why the output of EfficientNet B0 is two-dimension?

Tags: keras, computer-vision, efficientnet

i know from paper:the output of efficientnet b0 is (*,7,7,1280),right?if so,the globalAveragePooling2D will get ndim = 4,instead of 2.

```
        model=Sequential()
        inputS=(height,width,depth)
        chanDim=-1
        model.add(EfficientNetB0(inputS, include_top=True, weights='imagenet'))
        model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
        model.add(Dense(1024))
        model.add(Activation("swish"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))
        model.add(Dense(256))
        model.add(Activation("swish"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))
        model.add(Dense(32))
        model.add(Activation("tanh"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))
        model.add(Dense(classes))
        model.add(Activation("softmax"))
        return model
```

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer global_average_pooling2d_2: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2
```

Comment: Paste directly the code and error log, instead of images.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time to ask question here.And i have updated it.Please help....

Answer (score 1):

That is because you set `include_top` to `True`, meaning that classification layers are included in the model, so the output shape of the whole model is `(samples, classes)`, that's probably not what you want.

As you want feature maps, you should set `include_top` to `False` in the instantiation of `EfficientNetB0`.